# Clarifications on the concept of Trinity according to Catholic creed

Tags: catholicism, trinity

I'm trying to understand what the correct understanding would be according to Catholic teachings.

From what I understand the concept of Trinity is 3 persons who are one and the same.  Is this correct?

So from this understanding, would you say God(Father) sent Jesus or would you say God(Father) is Jesus also?

I was reading a catholic website and it was describing their beliefs and it mentioned that Jesus will sit at the right hand of God(Father).

Is Jesus God or not?  And is he All-Knowing like God?

Thank you.

Comment: There are a number of questions on this site about the Trinity already. I expect one of them at least already answers your question. The one above seems the most likely. Have you read these other answers?

Comment: @Flimzy is that link in the question reliable? what is that website 'chrisitan apologetics'.

Comment: That link is to another question on this same web site. I have no idea what you're talking about when you say `what is that website 'christian apologetics'`

Comment: The first answer links to carm.org = Christian Apologetics and Research Ministry. @user1361315, if you have doubts about that site, you should check [our other Trinity questions and answers](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinity) which are full of sources.

Answer (score 4):

**From what I understand the concept of Trinity is 3 persons who are one and the same. Is this correct?**

Yes. But your statement is incomplete. Trinity is 3 persons who are one and the same **God** NOT one and the same **person**.

**So from this understanding, would you say God(Father) sent Jesus or would you say God(Father) is Jesus also?**

Catholics claim God the Father sent Jesus. They do *not* say God the Father is Jesus, because Father, Son and the Holy Spirit are three distinct persons.

**Is Jesus God or not? And is he All-Knowing like God?**

Jesus is God and so he is omniscience (knows everything that there is to know).

I assume the distinction and the similarity between the three persons of the trinity is causing you confusion.

> <sup>251</sup> In order to articulate the dogma of the Trinity, the Church had to develop her own terminology with the help of certain notions of philosophical origin: 'substance', 'person/hypostasis', 'relation'.
>
> <sup>252</sup>The Church uses
>
> - the term 'substance' (rendered also at times by 'essence' or 'nature') to designate the divine being in its unity,
> - the term 'person' or 'hypostasis' to designate the Father, Son and Holy Spirit in the real distinction among them, and
> - the term 'relation' to designate the fact that their distinction lies in the relationship of each to the others.
>
> <sup>253</sup>The Trinity is One. We do not confess three Gods, but one God in three persons, the 'consubstantial Trinity'
>
> <sup>254/255</sup> The divine persons are really distinct from one another and are relative to one another.
>
> (From CCC)

Comment: I was reading a passage where Jesus cursed a tree for not having fruit http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+11%3A12-25 when he went to get fruit, so I was confused if all 3 'persons' are All-knowing or not.  And when Jesus says the Father is greater than I?  So to me they don't seem equal or omniscience. How should this be understood?

Comment: To @user1361315: That's a completely different question. I'll try to keep it short or you have to update the question so that I can give a detailed answer (oly 500 chars allowed here). Catholics believe Christ had two nature. Human and Divine. Son of God assumed a human nature in order to accomplish our salvation and in this human nature he did not know everything. Though he existed as God, he did not regard _qualities_ of being God (like omniscience) as something to be grasped. (Phil 2:6)

Comment: Is there anything from Jesus's own words which indicate this?

Comment: Jesus is God. At the same time  He took birth as a human in the womb of Virgin Mary and became human. This inarnation was necessary in order to shed his blood once and for all time to come (as was done in Jewish custom by spilling of  blood through sacrifice of lamb etc., which was valid for only a year) for the atonement of sins of those who would believe in Him as messaiah as well as of those who died prior to His sacrifice by having faith in God's forgiveness and promissed salvation.

Comment: So Jesus was both human experiencing pain, hunger like us as well as God in deeds and will(having power over nature, power to forgive sins, power over winds, waves, power to make whole the crippled body parts, power over death, power to rise from His own death and so on)

Comment: @jayyeshu But jewish custom/tenets would never except God on earth, nor the trinity, and son of god to them just meant a noble person, not a literal sense.  This point needs some discussion. thanks!